# How to perform Group by then use DISTINCT on other column in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have just starting learning PIG and need small help with the question below . thanks in advance !
For eg: I have input like:

**Occupation     Category    Name**

```
Actress       Acting     Marion Cotillard
Actor         Acting     Liam Nelson
Tennis Plyr   Athletics  Roger Federer
Football Plyr Athletics  Neymar
Actor         Acting     Tom Hanks
Actress       Acting     Elizabeth Banks
US Senator    Politics   Elizabeth Warren
Football Plyr Athletics  Mesut Ozil
```

I want to know how many types are there in single category.
For eg:- Acting has two types one is Actress and other is Actor. Hence , result will be 2.
Problem facing : Not able to DISTINCT the output from 'group by Category' using 'Occupation' column. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
x= load '<data>' using PigStorage('\t') as (occupation:chararray,category:chararray,name:chararray);

 x_grouped= group x by category;

x_grouped_distinct= foreach x_grouped { cat= distinct $1.occupation; generate $0, cat, COUNT(cat);}; 

dump x_grouped_distinct;
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinct first and then Group By Category.Assuming you have already loaded the data into relation A.

Select the 2 columns after the load.

Distinct the relation

Group By category

Count Occupation for each Category

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE Occupation as Occupation,Category as Category;
C = DISTINCT B;
D = GROUP C BY $1; 
E = FOREACH D GENERATE group,COUNT(C.Occupation); 
DUMP E;
```

[image: Output]

Comment: facing below error, actual data has more fields like year , date etc
Caused by: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (1999,actor,1/11/99,Acting,Michael J. Fox), 2nd :(1999,Comedian,1/12/99,Comedy,Sandra Bernhard) (common cause: "JOIN" then "FOREACH ... GENERATE foo.bar" should be "foo::bar" ).

In the last it says :
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias fin 
fin is my final bag hence the short name 'fin' . Please help if you find time for this.

Comment: @PriyanshuSharma I've edited the script and added the output.

Comment: even i also did your this correction  before posting the mentioned error... nothing is wrong with your script... After examining I found version compatibility issue. Thanks for your help , the main problem is solved finally by your script. I can take care of other issues now :)